# Unable to set property 'className' on Term Store Manager after CU

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I have recently upgraded two SP2010 environments to June 2014 CU (14.0.7125.5002).

Not sure if it is related (most probably yes) but if I get into Term Store Manager from Internet Explorer, I cannot browse through the terms properly, as there is no "up" and "down" arrows.

This is being caused by a script error within the treecontrol.js file in the layouts folder, which as far as I know is a default SharePoint file, that has not been changed intentionally.

The details are as follows:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'className' of undefined or null reference
File: treecontrol.js, Line: 40, Column: 2862

var $1=$get('frameForReuseTreesContainer');    
$1.className='';//error here
```

If anyone has ever had this and/or has any ideas on what to do, please advise.

BTW, works fine in Firefox and Chrome and it is not JQuery related, as same thing happens with OOTB master page. Sounds like a problem with the Update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely because the javascript files have been updated but not made 100% backwards compatible by Microsoft (wouldn't be the first time).

When the javascript files start throwing around errors like that you can usually go to an environment where it works and copy over the working file to the non-working server.

Comment: I guess this is the best I can do, thanks, it appears to work. Reverted to SP2 version of TreeControl.js

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ULSXaE() { var o = new Object; o.ULSTeamName = "Office Server"; o.ULSFileName = "TreeControl.js"; return o; }
        if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase() == "/_layouts/termstoremanager.aspx") {
            Type.registerNamespace('Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy');
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TreeNodeCollection.prototype = { get_count: function () { ULSXaE:; if (this.get_element().lastChild && SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrEmptyString(this.get_element().lastChild.id)) { return this.get_$2_0().length - 1; } else { return this.get_$2_0().length; } }, get_id: function () { ULSXaE:; return this.get_element().id; }, set_id: function (value) { ULSXaE:; this.get_element().id = value; return value; }, get_firstChild: function () { ULSXaE:; if (this.get_element().firstChild) { if (this.get_element().firstChild.tagName !== 'LI' && this.get_element().firstChild.nextSibling) { return this.get_element().firstChild.nextSibling.control; } else { return this.get_element().firstChild.control; } } return null; }, get_lastChild: function () { ULSXaE:; if (this.get_element().lastChild) { if (this.get_element().lastChild.tagName !== 'LI' && this.get_element().lastChild.previousSibling) { return this.get_element().lastChild.previousSibling.control; } else { return this.get_element().lastChild.control; } } return null; }, get_$2_0: function () { ULSXaE:; return this.get_element().childNodes; }, $2_1: function ($p0) { var $0 = null; for (var $1 = 0; $1 < this.get_count() ; $1++) { $0 = this.get_element().childNodes[$1].control; if ($p0 === $0.get_text()) { return $0; } } return null; }, getChildById: function (id) { ULSXaE:; var $0 = null; for (var $1 = 0; $1 < this.get_count() ; $1++) { if (id === this.get_element().childNodes[$1].id) { $0 = this.get_element().childNodes[$1].control; break; } } return $0; }, addChild: function (child) { ULSXaE:; if (child) { if (this.get_tree() && this.get_tree().get_enableFiltering() && this.get_tree().get_filter().evaluate(child)) { return; } else if (this.get_element().childNodes && this.get_element().childNodes.length > 0 && SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrEmptyString(this.get_element().childNodes[this.get_element().childNodes.length - 1].id)) { this.get_element().insertBefore(child.get_domNode(), this.get_element().childNodes[this.get_element().childNodes.length - 1]); } else { this.get_element().appendChild(child.get_domNode()); } } }, $2_2: function ($p0) { if ($p0) { this.get_element().appendChild($p0); } }, $2_3: function ($p0, $p1) { if ($p0 && $p1) { this.get_element().replaceChild($p0, $p1); } }, $2_4: function ($p0, $p1) { if ($p0 && $p1) { this.get_element().insertBefore($p0.get_domNode(), $p1.get_domNode()); } }, $2_5: function () { ULSXaE:; if (this.get_element().style.display !== '') { this.get_element().style.display = ''; } }, $2_6: function () { ULSXaE:; if (this.get_element().style.display !== 'none') { this.get_element().style.display = 'none'; } }, $2_7: function () { ULSXaE:; while (this.get_element().firstChild) { this.get_element().removeChild(this.get_element().firstChild); } }, $2_8: function ($p0) { if (!$p0 || !$p0.get_domNode()) { return; } var $0 = this.get_element().parentNode; $p0.get_domNode().id = this.get_element().id; $0.replaceChild($p0.get_domNode(), this.get_element()); if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer && Sys.Browser.version === 8 && document.documentMode === 9) { var $1 = $get('frameForReuseTreesContainer'); $1.className = ''; $1.className = 'FrameForTrees'; } }, get_domNode: function () { ULSXaE:; return this.get_element(); }, get_tree: function () { ULSXaE:; return this.$2_9; }, set_tree: function (value) { ULSXaE:; this.$2_9 = value; return value; }, $2_9: null, hasMoreChildBefore: false, hasMoreChildAfter: false, lastChildId: null }
        }
    </script>
```